# Database terminology - what vocabulary should I use to differentiate between restoring a database and executing developer scripts?

Tags: sql, database, deployment, naming-conventions

My development team has been over-using the term  "deploy", and it seems to have lost its meaning.

What are short, clear, and concise terms to describe each of the following?

- Restoring a database from a baseline
- Executing developer scripts (including data updates, schema changes, etc)
- Doing both in a single batch file

I currently have several batch files that perform these functions, but they are all ambiguously called `deploy.bat`, and need better names that describe what they do.

Comment: 1) Restore, 2) Update, 3) Deploy. 4) This kind of questions shouldn't really be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with:

1. DatabaseRestore
2. DatabaseUpdates
3. DatabaseInstall

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I didn't go with these, but thanks :)  I went with `database_restore`, `database_scripts`, and `database_deploy`.